# How to shrink material/particles on plane while maintaining overall size of plane

Tags: uv

Here's some grass I made that I'm happy with:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DSZl.jpg

I want the camera to remain at this height (50ft) because I'm simulating a model plane being at that height.
However, I want the grass to appear the way it would from 50 ft up, which means scaling down this grass and maybe tiling it? If I just scale it down then it will no longer fill the frame, so I think I need to do some sort of UV stuff.

My setup is a plane with [this](https://kaimoisch.com/textures/mossy-ground-mixed-2x2-seamless/) as it's main material:

[image: base color (environment texture?)]

and then a particlesystem hair that looks like grass. Also, I have [this](https://polyhaven.com/a/evening_road_01) as my HDRI but that's probably not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to do this, that will tile as you suspect, is to use collection instances.  Move the particle emitter to its own collection, then add a collection instance from the shift-a menu in the 3D viewport.  You can add as many instances as you'd like and move them around:

[image]

Otherwise, it's necessary to increase the size of the object (not by scaling, which will also scale particles) as well as increase the number of particles.  If you scale the emitter up three-fold in edit mode, you will need to to increase the number of particles nine-fold; to maintain the same density, the number of particles is proportional to the size increase squared.  This will (probably) *not* tile, which may or may not be good depending on what you want.

You can increase the size of the emitter via an array modifier instead of scaling.  If you do so, you will need to make sure that the array modifier is above (before) the particle instance in the modifier stack and that the particle system has "Use Modifier Stack" enabled in properties/particle/emission/source.  You will still need to increase the number of particles as above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Question though, do these solutions keep the scale of the background material 1? Put another way, I want to zoom in and see what I see now. Maybe I don't want this as the material will be tiled though?

Comment: @kevinlinxc of the emitter material?  I see, I was focusing on the particles, but the two are really different questions.  What you want to do with a material depends on the material, and what you have shown isn't enough to say; I would need to see the shader nodes for the emitter, and preferably any UV maps as well.  Until then, the answer is, "array or collection is instance will probably do what you want; scaling in edit probably won't; try it out."